# Two buy orders at the same exact time, no miner tips included, but lower GWEI order wins. How is this possible?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, gas, mining, hash

question for the group: if two buyers submit a Buy at the exact same time, one chooses 300 gwei and the other chooses 400gwei, no Miner tips on either one, is there some scenario where the 300gwei one still wins? Could it involve blocks?

Comment: Read this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/89665, miners have full control and they can use any order. The geth client uses an algorithm that sorts by gas price https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6111, but it is open source and a miner can modify and uses a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Im not super familiar with mining so i might be wrong but the only scenario i can think of where the 300gwei order would pass over the 400gwei order would be if the block is almost full and the 300gwei transaction fits in it but not the 400gwei one